# gsutil returns "Unauthorized client"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil, gcloud

I was in the process of syncing a folder with 130k files to Google Cloud Storage. After several thousand images have been uploaded, I started to get the following message for each file that gsutil was trying to copy:

```
Your "Oauth 2.0 User Account" credentials are invalid. For more help, see "gsutil help creds", or re-run the gsutil config command (see "gsutil help config").
Failure: unauthorized_client.
```

I tried every trick I could think of. `gcloud auth login` works as usual, but it does not resolve the problem. `gcloud auth list` shows correct account. `gsutil config` warns me that it is no longer necessary - I ran it anyway, and it worked as expected, but it did not solve the problem. Deleting `.boto` file and running `gsutil config` again did not help either.

At this moment I thought that may be I ran into some quota limit. I could not find any references in the documentation or on Cloud Console about any quota on file uploads. To verify this theory I tried to sync the same files from a different computer. And it worked, suggesting that there is no bucket or app quota. After a few thousand files, however, the second computer started showing the same error messages.

Another important note. Initially I tried to copy files using the Cloud Console, but it was going too slowly. Still, the console was able to upload more than 25k files - significantly more than `gsutil` tool. I terminated this upload myself (25k very small files in 24 hours is too slow...)

Does anyone know what this is happening? And how can I restore the credentials now?

Comment: We've experienced the same issue. As far as I can see this is probably related to a new release of boto: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/v2.6.0.html

Upon stepping through the code I've found the following issue. Hopefully this solves something: https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2302

Comment: Hi - what version of gsutil are you using? Does this happen with the current version (4.1)? Also, are you running the gcloud version of gsutil or the standalone? I ask because gsutil config is only used for the standalone version.

Comment: I run 4.1. I did run gsutil update, though, to get this version because gcloud components update was not upgrading to gsutil to 4.1.

Comment: Do you have prefer_api=xml in the GSUtil section of your boto config file? We believe this is a bug (which we'll fix) in the GCS code in boto, but it should only impact you if you're using the boto release that has this bug - which shouldn't be true if you're either using gsutil v4 without prefer_api=xml, or if you're using one of the gsutil distributions that bundles a copy of boto that didn't include this bug.

Comment: prefer_api = xml is commented out in .boto.

Comment: Are you running a gsutil distribution that doesn't include a bundled boto (like one installed from PyPi instead of from a gsutil tar.gz file)? If so, you need to update your boto to boto release 2.29.1, which has the fix for this problem.

Comment: Installing boto 2.29.1 did not help. Should I somehow update gcloud or gsutil after installing new boto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install boto release 2.29.1 (thanks, Mike Schwartz), and then update gcloud.

Install boto via pip:

```
$ pip install boto
```

Or install boto from source:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
$ cd boto
$ python setup.py install
```

Reinstall gcloud:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
~./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

Fortunately, gcloud performs in place update, so it's relatively fast. Finally,

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: We're building a new gsutil release that includes the updated boto with this fix. I'll reply on this StackOverlow issue once it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

this problem should now be fixed if your run:

gsutil update

(which will get you to gsutil v4.2)

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: there is the same problem in gsutil v4.5

Comment: I'm seeing this using the standalone gsutil v4.6 (the latest at the time of this writing).  Performing an operation like 'gsutil -m acl ch -R ...' results in the "Oauth 2.0 User Account credentials are invalid" for some of the worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful to anyone, I had the same problem but Andrei's exact solution did not work for me. What worked was reinstalling boto via pip (`pip install boto`) and then updating gcloud components (`sudo gcloud components update`).

(Then running `gcloud auth login` was not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I solved it by running `gsutil config`.
This creates a new `.boto` with new credentials.